# Method being executed out of order in Scala

Tags: scala

I don't know what am I missing , may be its something minor, but here is the problem

println() is being called out of order.
i.e. Output that I get is

Line two.

Line one

Shouldn't it be reversed?

I do know that that "Line two" is out of main method, but what is the reason,
I tried searching, but couldn't get to the bottom.

```
object oneToTen {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Line one")
  }

  println("Line two.")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this observation is quite correct. By the construction of the object, each object initializer is executed. Every method call that is performed outside of a method body can be seen as "constructor".

Answer (score 7):

In Scala, everything that is in the body and that is not a variable declaration is part of the constructor.
As `oneToTen` is a scala object, an instance of it is created and then the main method is invoked.

Answer (score 4):

This is how Scala classes/objects are supposed to work. Everything declared directly in class/object body will be called upon instantiation.